# Daisy chain or dedicated outlets in wiring my RV?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

What will happen if I dedicate each outlet to its own breaker in an RV??
I thought I was doing it the right way and may have cost myself a lot of extra money and put my safety on the line. I already have plastic and insulation up... do I have to take down and ponytail my outlets?

Comment: Can you describe "ponytail my outlets"? That's a new term to me. Also, just for clarity, are you indicating that you've already wired each outlet to its own breaker, running the wire through the walls, then insulated and put up "plastic" (vapor barrier, interior panels, something)? Or are you now (after insulation and plastic) at the stage of adding the wiring? (and a wave from a fellow Hoosier! :)

Comment: I'm guessing she meant pigtail. Of course, that's optional when running a series of outlets anyway.

Comment: Welcome, Tina. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know what to do next to resolve your post. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

If each outlet is on its own breaker then you have probably used more cable compared to having two or more on a circuit, as well as paid for a few extra breakers.

What you have not done is compromised your safety.

This way if any one outlet "sees" or detects a fault then the other outlets will continue - unless the inverter shuts down.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't have to remove and vapor barriers or insulation. There's nothing wrong with tying each outlet to it's own breaker. It actually makes sense because because there's not an abundance of outlets in an rv and it's easy to overload them and then you loose all on the one breaker. It probably didn't cost that much because you already had to buy the wire and it comes in a box or reel and the breakers are pretty cheap. Just don't use the backstabs on the outlets. Terminate the wires on the screw terminals. Another advantage is that if one outlet acts up, it's easy to troubleshoot and you don't lose the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is pigtail the wiring together in the breaker box so that you can put two outlets on one breaker.  This might be wise if you are close to running out of breaker space -- it's always good to save a few slots for later updates.